# How can I embed an interactive dashboard in a Google Map marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, embed, dashboard, marker

For example, imagine I have a marker placed in Maine on a Google map. Upon clicking the marker would pop up this interactive dashboard within Google Map itself:

https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/moose-crashes-maine?gallery=votd

In the code:

```js
      if(props.content){
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content:props.content
        });

        marker.addListener('click',function(){
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
```

I made a marker listen for a click and when it does, it opens a completely blank info window.

I can convert the dashboard into an image and insert it that way, but that's not what I want. I want to embed the dashboard to retain its interaction.

Is this possible?

Here is the dashboard's embed code:

```html
<div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1552237426081' style='position: relative'><noscript>
  <a href='#'>
    <img alt=' ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Mo&#47;MooseCrashesinMaine&#47;MooseCrashes2010-2017Version3&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' />
    </a>
</noscript>
  <object class='tableauViz' style='display:none;'>
  <param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' />
  <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value='' />
  <param name='name' value='MooseCrashesinMaine&#47;MooseCrashes2010-2017Version3' />
  <param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
  <param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Mo&#47;MooseCrashesinMaine&#47;MooseCrashes2010-2017Version3&#47;1.png' />
  <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' />
  <param name='display_static_image' value='yes' />
  <param name='display_spinner' value='yes' />
  <param name='display_overlay' value='yes' />
  <param name='display_count' value='yes' />
</object>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1552237426081');
  var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];
  vizElement.style.width = '1100px';
  vizElement.style.height = '877px';
  var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
  scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';
  vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display the embed dashboard by inserting the element in the infoWindow, then running the associated javascript in a "domready" event listener on the infoWindow.

```
var props = {
  content: "https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/moose-crashes-maine?gallery=votd",
  id: "viz1552237426081"
};
if (props.id) {
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: document.getElementById(props.id)
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
      var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1552237426081');
      var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];
      vizElement.style.width = '1100px';
      vizElement.style.height = '877px';
      var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
      scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';
      vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);
    });
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/0xLf8nc6/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var props = {
  content: "https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/moose-crashes-maine?gallery=votd",
  id: "viz1552237426081"
};

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: 45.253783,
      lng: -69.4454689
    }
  });
  // Maine, USA (45.253783, -69.44546889999998)
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 45.253783,
      lng: -69.4454689
    },
    map: map
  });
  if (props.id) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: document.getElementById(props.id)
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
        var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1552237426081');
        var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];
        vizElement.style.width = '1100px';
        vizElement.style.height = '877px';
        var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';
        vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);
      });
    });
  }
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tableauPlaceholder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
<div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1552237426081' style='position: relative'><noscript>
  <a href='#'>
    <img alt=' ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Mo&#47;MooseCrashesinMaine&#47;MooseCrashes2010-2017Version3&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none; height:877px; width:1100px;' />
    </a>
</noscript>
  <object class='tableauViz' style='display:none;'>
  <param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' />
  <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value='' />
  <param name='name' value='MooseCrashesinMaine&#47;MooseCrashes2010-2017Version3' />
  <param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
  <param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Mo&#47;MooseCrashesinMaine&#47;MooseCrashes2010-2017Version3&#47;1.png' />
  <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' />
  <param name='display_static_image' value='yes' />
  <param name='display_spinner' value='yes' />
  <param name='display_overlay' value='yes' />
  <param name='display_count' value='yes' />
</object>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
</script>
```

Comment: It works in jsfiddle, but using it and testing it locally only pops up a small tiny white box with nothing in it. How do I identify the issue?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the `<div>` from the embed code on the page.  The jsfiddle loads that into the infowindow, then runs the javascript the makes it interactive in the domready event handler function.

Answer (score 0):

Just add  the link  to the infowindow content, 
and in general add  the html code you prefer for manage  infowindow content

```
if(props.content){
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:props.content +
  '<a href="https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/moose-crashes-maine?gallery=votd"'>my_link</a>'
 });

 marker.addListener('click',function(){
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
 });
```